# Trying to close an active TCP Connection, but getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, tcp, error-handling

I have a web application using ASP.net c#, javascript and jQuery.

I am trying to close certain active TCP connection in my PAGE_UNLOAD event.

Here is my code -

```
IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.Resolve(camIP).AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint remEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 80);

foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
{
    if (c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() == remEndPoint.ToString())
    {
        Socket mySocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            mySocket.Bind(c.LocalEndPoint);
            mySocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            mySocket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try and bind I get the following error - "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

The TCP connection is created by setting the src of img control -

```
CameraIframe.Src = @"http://" + CameraHiddenFieldUsername.Value + ":" +
    CameraHiddenFieldPassword.Value + "@" + camIP + @"/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?fps=" +
    CameraHiddenFieldfps.Value + "&compression=" + CameraHiddenFieldcompression.Value +
    "&resolution=320x240&text=0&date=0&clock=0&eek=" + DateTime.Now.ToBinary();
```

I am new to socket programming, so any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the socket is held by some process. Use netstat -o to find which one.

Comment: Is there no way to force close the socket?  The socket has a PID and the state is established.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem when closing or 'deleting'. It's a problem when ***binding.*** Please fix your title accordingly. You're trying to bind a socket that is already bound, or trying to bind it to a local port < 1024.

What you're doing doesn't begin to make sense. If they're your own connections, just *close* them. 
You don't need to create a new socket for that.

And when you do create a new socket, you don't need to bind it unless you're going to listen with it, and shutting it down without previously connecting it or subsequently closing it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: How do you close them?